# When I convert an expression using shortcut operators the output is wrong

Tags: python

I read that if I have the following expression:

```
variable = variable op expression
```

It can be simplified and shown as follows:

```
variable op= expression
```

For example: `i = i + 2 * j` --> `i += 2 * j`

However, I have used the previous example in `a = a / 2 * b` --> `a /= 2 * b`

Let `a=6` and `b=3`. Using both values in `a=a/2*b`, the output is 9. However, in the case of `a /= 2* b`, the output is 1

Comment: You're changing the order of operations; `a /= 2 * b` is `a = a / (2 * b)`, whereas `a = a / 2 * b` is `a = (a / 2) * b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are changing the order of operations.
a = a / 2 * b is interpreted as "Divide a by 2, then multiply by b, then store the result in a", or a = (a / 2) * b.

a /= 2 * b is interpreted as "Multiply 2 by b, then divide a by the result, and store the final result in a", or a = a / (2 * b).

I hope this helps.